# Referencing inline scripts from update panels in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sharepoint, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to work around an issue with using inline scripts in update panels. The issue is something I might commonly solve by using Sys.Application.add_load() or creating a RegisterStatupScript() script with the ScriptManager. However, neither solution works in this case.

Here is the problem.

Update panel on asp.net (in this case, SharePoint) page:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Load" />
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Lets say in the code behind we add a user control to the placeholder when the button is clicked.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyControl ctrl = new MyControl();
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(ctrl);

    UpdatePanel1.Update();
}
```

Finally, let's say our user control has some inline scripts.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myInt = 1;
    alert(typeof myInt);
</script>
```

Putting the above together and running it would lead to an update panel that is empty (except the button) by default- get's some data added when the button is clicked that looks like the javascript above. **The problem is the javascript code above will never fire**.

In my real life case the user control is not terribly complex- it has a repeater that is populated when the control is loaded then some inline javascript which transforms the repeater data a bit. The data comes through but the javascript is never executed and throws no errors.

Attempted solution:
Wrap inline javascript in a function called initMyCode() then use:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.getType(), UniqueID, "initMyCode()", true);
```

...on the user control page load event. This fails as initMyCode() cannot be found within the page.

Anyone have a workable solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("initMyCode")){ 
 string script =@"function initMyCode(){var myInt = 1;
   alert(typeof myInt);}
 Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(initMyCode);"
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.getType(), initMyCode, script, true);

}
```

Or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function initMyCode(){
 var myInt = 1;
 alert(typeof myInt);}
 Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(initMyCode);
</script>
```

Comment: The problem with this approach: I am trying to avoid adding the entire block of returned javascript into a variable and load it all with RegisterStartupScript(). The javascript I am returning is dynamic and creates graphs/charts. Any other ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Have you already tried adding your code in the ["ready"](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) of jQuery?